# Does differentiability almost everywhere imply continuity on an interval?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity, examples-counterexamples

I suppose there are differentiable almost everywhere functions whose sets of discontinuities are dense. How to prove or disprove it?

Additionally, is Thomae's function $T(x)$ raised to some power greater than 2 an example? (With 2 it isn't differentiable anywhere by Hurwitz's theorem.) Or maybe $\begin{cases}
e^{-\frac 1 {T(x)}} & \textrm{if $x\in\mathbb Q$} \\
0 & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$?

Comment: Is $1/x$ not a counterexample? It is differentiable almost everywhere, yet not continuous. What do I not get here?

Comment: @TheCount: such function has a single point of discontinuity, while the OP is looking for a function with a dense subset of discontinuities.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks. The title lead me to think OP just wanted a counterexample to the assertion "differentiable a.e. implies continuous" and that the first sentence was a misunderstanding. Appreciate the clarification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By Khinchin's theorem, for almost every real $x$ there are at most finitely many rationals $p/q$ (where $p,q$ are integers with $q > 0$) with $|x - p/q| < 1/q^3$.  Consider the function $f(x)$ such that $f(p/q) = 1/q^4$ for rational $p/q$ in lowest terms, $f(x) = 0$ otherwise.  Note that if $x$ is irrational and $|x - p/q| \ge 1/q^3$, $$ \left|\frac{f(x) - f(p/q)}{x - p/q}\right| \le \frac{1/q^4}{1/q^3} = \frac{1}{q} $$
and as a result  $f'(x)$ exists and is $0$ for any $x$ in Khinchin's set.
But $f$ is discontinuous at every rational.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're using Khinchin's theorem for $\psi(q)=\frac 1 {q^2}$. And then you take such $f$ that $f(\frac 1 q)=o(\psi(q))$. But a version of $\psi$ with any exponent greater than 1 would fulfill the theorem's hypothesis. And for $f$ the exponent needn't be bumped by 1, just by an arbitralily small amount. So, was I right in my above hypothesis that Thomae's function raised to any power greater than 2 can serve as an example?

Answer (score 4):

You may consider the function $f(x) = \text{sign}(x) e^{-|x|}$ and an enumeration $q_1,q_2,\ldots$ of the elements of $\mathbb{Q}$. If you manage to prove that
$$ F(x)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{f(n(x-q_n))}{2^n} $$
is almost everywhere differentiable, you have your counter-example.
 For short: condensation of singularities.